# Can we connect to a SQLite database which is in FTP from iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite, ftp

i have used FTP to download and upload files from and to ftp
now, my doubt is can we connect to the sqlite database which is in ftp from iphone ?

Comment: You should give more information.

Comment: Things aren't actually **in** ftp; ftp is a transfer method.  However, you should be able to connect to it after you download it.

Comment: to connect to a database we ill provide that data base path know there if we give database path which is in ftp it wont work? (like ftp://ftp.xxxx.net/test.sqlite)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FTP protocol is not completely usable for partial uploads/downloads (unless you have custom FTP server). SFTP (SSH File Transfer Protocol) is better for this.

Now, SQLite supports extension mechanisms, using which it's possible to encrypt blocks of storage data (and there are products that do this). The same extension mechanisms can potentially be used to store the real data elsewhere (eg. across network accessible via SFTP).

So in general the answer to your question is *yes*, but the devil is in details.